# Django tamplate can not loaded

Tags: python, django

I called a template in the django render function, but django cannot find it

here is the django view code:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def home_page(request):
    return render(request, "index.html")
```

And after this I tried to check my settings.py and urls.py, but found nothing, and the file is also in the tamplate subfolder of the app

here is the directory structure:

```
│  .gitignore
│  db.sqlite3
│  funcational_test.py
│  manage.py
│
├─Terminal_equipment_management
│  │  asgi.py
│  │  settings.py
│  │  urls.py
│  │  view.py
│  │  wsgi.py
│  │  __init__.py
│  │
│  └─__pycache__
│
└─webui
    │  admin.py
    │  apps.py
    │  models.py
    │  tests.py
    │  views.py
    │  __init__.py
    │
    ├─migrations
    │
    ├─templates
           index.html
```

the settings.py is:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "api",
    "webui",
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

urls.py is:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from webui import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.home_page, name="home_page"),
]
```

But when I visit localhost:8000/, Django will report TemplateDoesNotExist at /
here is some Error Message:
Template-loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\index.html (Source does not exist)

When I copied the files to the above two folders, the template took effect.
I can't be sure what happened

By Google Translate

Comment: The name of the directory is `templates`, not `tamplate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Template **DIRS**:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / "template"],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to put `s` for template folder names

```
└─webui
    │
    ├─tamplates
           index.html
```

Comment: After I tried to rename the template to templates, the template still cannot be loaded normally, and there is still TemplateDoesNotExist at /, I think maybe Django did not actively look for the templates folder in my app folder,I'm using Django 3.4.1 , Miniconda 3(Python3.9)

Answer (score 0):

First, `tamplates` should be `templates`.  Second, django looks inside a folder under templates for the app name. It seems redundant, and I agree, but that caused me issues when I was first using django.

```
└─webui
    │
    └─templates
         │
         └─webui
             │
             └─index.html
```